# spresense JP10/Ach マイク未接続時に録音するとホワイトノイズ系のノイズが乗ってしまう

Tags: spresense

お世話になります。
当方、spresenseをarduino IDEにて使用している者です。
表題につきまして、以下の通り解決しましたので共有いたします。

ー－ー－

【問題点】
spresenseのアナログマイク入力（JP10／Ach）を用いて録音（48kHz,24bit,wav形式,SDカードに保存)すると、
ホワイトノイズ系の大きなノイズ(-30dB程度)が乗ってしまう。

【解決】
setup関数内にて、wavヘッダを書き込むコードの記述がなかったことが原因。
（データ領域にヘッダーが書き込まれてしまい、24bit（3バイト）のデータの場合、チャンネルごとのデータの同期がずれ上位下位ビットが入れ替わった、ことが原因と思われます。）

コードを追記したところ、ノイズレベルが-90dB程度に改善しました。
(アナログマイクをJP10/Achにつなげて録音しても-60dB程度にて録音でき、正常動作いたしました。）

以下、サンプルコードを示します。

```
---------------------------------
  /* Write wav header (Write to top of file. File size is tentative.) */

  theRecorder->writeWavHeader(recFile);
  puts("Write Header!");

---------------------------------
```

以上、参考になるかわかりませんが、
何かのお役に立ちましたら幸いです。

よろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: なるほど！参考になりました！