# spresenseで4ch録音時、信号が別のチャンネルに移動してしまう

Tags: spresense

SPRESENSE　arduino　IDEにて、テストプログラムのrecorder wavを元に
パラメータを48kHz/4ch/16bit/wavとして録音試験を行っています。
ch1のみマイクを接続して、30分程度の録音を行っていますが
途中でch1の信号がch3に移動してしまう事象が頻繁に発生します。
このような事象の対策は何か考えられるでしょうか。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

どのような形で録音されているのかわからないですが、wavファイルは音声データはch0,ch1,ch2,ch3という形でインターリーブされて記録されます。
ですので、何らかの形でデータが欠落やずれを起こす場合、この図のようにずれることは自分も確認したことがあります。

また、wavヘッダの書き込みなどを間違えるとずれるという投稿もあります。

[spresense JP10/Ach マイク未接続時に録音するとホワイトノイズ系のノイズが乗ってしまう](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/89416/spresense-jp10-ach-%e3%83%9e%e3%82%a4%e3%82%af%e6%9c%aa%e6%8e%a5%e7%b6%9a%e6%99%82%e3%81%ab%e9%8c%b2%e9%9f%b3%e3%81%99%e3%82%8b%e3%81%a8%e3%83%9b%e3%83%af%e3%82%a4%e3%83%88%e3%83%8e%e3%82%a4%e3%82%ba%e7%b3%bb%e3%81%ae%e3%83%8e%e3%82%a4%e3%82%ba%e3%81%8c%e4%b9%97%e3%81%a3%e3%81%a6%e3%81%97%e3%81%be%e3%81%86)

御参考になれば。